# Using pointers to move between elements in struct

Tags: c, memory, struct

This is closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16405250/2148245).

I am writing some USB code using [`libusb`](http://www.libusb.org/). Looking at the source code of the library I see they are using pointers to parse data and fill `structs`.

Example:

From `libusb.h`:

```
struct libusb_endpoint_descriptor {
    uint8_t  bLength;
    uint8_t  bDescriptorType;
    uint8_t  bEndpointAddress;
    uint8_t  bmAttributes;
    uint16_t wMaxPacketSize;
    uint8_t  bInterval;
    uint8_t  bRefresh;
    uint8_t  bSynchAddress;
    const unsigned char *extra;
    int extra_length;
};
```

From `descriptor.c`:

```
struct libusb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint
unsigned char *buffer
int host_endian

usbi_parse_descriptor(buffer, "bbbbwbbb", endpoint, host_endian);
```

where `usbi_parse_descriptor` is:

```
int usbi_parse_descriptor(
        unsigned char *source, 
        const char *descriptor,
        void *dest, 
        int host_endian)
{
    unsigned char *sp = source;
    unsigned char *dp = dest;
    uint16_t w;
    const char *cp;

    for (cp = descriptor; *cp; cp++) {
        switch (*cp) {
        case 'b':    /* 8-bit byte */
                *dp++ = *sp++;
                break;
        case 'w':    /* 16-bit word, convert from little endian to CPU */
            dp += ((uintptr_t)dp & 1);    /* Align to word boundary */
            if (host_endian) {
                memcpy(dp, sp, 2);
            } else {
                w = (sp[1] << 8) | sp[0];
                *((uint16_t *)dp) = w;
            }
            sp += 2;
            dp += 2;
            break;
        }
    }

    return (int) (sp - source);
}
```

---

My question is the use of `char` pointers to traverse the buffer.

1. Couldn't one risk that `uint8_t` is aligned as an, e.g., `uint32_t` integer by the compiler – thus `*dp++` ending up at wrong address? 
   By wrong address I mean the address of the variables in struct `libusb_endpoint_descriptor` which `dp` points to:

   ```
   unsigned char *buffer = REPLY from request to USB device.
   struct libusb_endpoint_descriptor *endpoint;
   unsigned char *dp = (void*) endpoint;

     *dp = buffer[0] ==> struct libusb_endpoint_descriptor -> bLength
   *++dp = buffer[1] ==> struct libusb_endpoint_descriptor -> bDescriptorType
   ... v                                                         ^
       |                                                         |
       +--- does this guaranteed align with this ----------------+
   ```
2. What happens by this?:

   ```
   dp += ((uintptr_t)dp & 1);    /* Align to word boundary */
   ```

If a struct is something like this in memory:

```
ADDRESS  TYPE      NAME
0x000a0  uint8_t   var1
0x000a1  uint16_t  var2
0x000a3  uint8_t   var3
```

and `dp` points to `var1`; `0x000a0`, what would the above statement do?

Comment: Partial answer:

    dp += ((uintptr_t)dp & 1);    /* Align to word boundary */

is treating dp as an integer representation of the pointer (using the appropriate size on the machine to express pointers). If the pointer is pointing to an odd address, it adds 1 to dp. Doing so makes dp be aligned on a 16-bit boundary. Continuing on, if dp points to var1, the statement leaves dp unchanged. If it points to &var2, the statement moves dp to &var3

Comment: Actually it moves dp to the second byte of var2, not to var3 (var2 is not aligned).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your second question, an address is simply an integer it's just the compiler that uses it to signify a memory location. What the expression `((uintptr_t)dp & 1)` does it to first convert it to a proper integer (the type `uintptr_t` is an integer big enough to hold a pointer), and check if the least significant bit is set or not. If the bit is not set the result of the expression is zero, which means that the address is even and 16-bit aligned. If the bit *is* set that means that the address is uneven and that it's not 16-bit aligned.

The fun thing about this expression is that it will result in either `0` or `1` being the result, depending on if the bit is not set or if it is. If the bit is not set then `0` is added to the already 16-bit aligned address, resulting in no change. If on the other hand the address is not 16-bit aligned the expression results in `1` being added to the address, automatically aligning it to a 16-bit boundary.

Comment: So an `uint16_t`is always aligned to an 16-bit address? Is this guaranteed? Or put another way – is this safe code?

Comment: @Zimzalabim No there is no guarantee that a 16-bit variable is aligned to a 16-bit boundary, which means that the code you show is potentially dangerous. However, unless asked _not_ to, all compilers I know of (old and new) will align variables larger than 8 bits to a word boundary, as it normally speeds up access. Also, the structure itself makes sure that the 16-bit variable is placed on the correct boundary.

Comment: It may be that this code deals with some USB specification that asks for some kind of alignment, and in that case the code would be safe, isn't it? The concern would be about the alignment of `unsigned char` but that I thought is guaranteed to be `1`.

Comment: @s.bandara: The USB specification specify various types of requests to e.g. control pipes. Here it is `9.4.3 Get descriptor` [pp 253 of USB 2.0](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/) – which return a 8-bit buffer with data as specified in table 9-13 on pp 269.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: And by *word boundary* I assume you mean size of AX, CX, DX, etc. registers? As in *real mode*, (typically 16 bit), largest size. It is implied trough context of what you write, but ask only to be sure. And is this true for 64-bit environment as well?

Answer (score 1):

1. Not sure, I wouldn't bet on the standard guaranteeing it, but at least on most PC platforms it should work.
2. `dp += ((uintptr_t)dp & 1);` rounds `dp` up to the next multiple of 2. If `dp` is already even, the statement has no effect.

Comment: Regarding pt. 1. I find it a bit strange if they use something that *might work*. I was wondering about doing something similar myself, - but only if I can say it **do** work.

Comment: I think alignment, rather than undefined, is implementation-defined. So if your platform spec says it works, it does.

Comment: Thanks. Yes – here is where I'm at a halt. I have tried to find some compiler flags, comments or other in the library that supports/confirms this, but with no luck. As it is a library for both Linux, BSD, OS X (Darwin) and Windows. It becomes a two part *thing* for me. 1. How can I safely use this myself, not being to platform bound, (if at all). 2. Is the `libusb` a good choice, or should I look elsewhere. Guess I'll have to read on.

Answer (score 1):

To address your first question, `dest` points to some memory to which to write to. `void *` tells you there is no particular type declared, it's just a chunk of memory. The `switch` block tests what's expected and either increments the pointer by one byte or two. The way this is done is safe because `unsigned char` is guaranteed to be aligned at `sizeof(char)`, which is `1`.

**EDIT**: What is unsafe about this is that `dest` in this case points to a  `libusb_endpoint_descriptor` with assumptions of its alignment expressed in `descriptor`. These assumptions depend on padding expectations that are not guaranteed. It may be that this code here relies on compiler options for packing.

Comment: Yes, that I get, but my concern was the target. As in e.g. `dp->bInterval`. If that one is aligned.

Comment: I see. This may work then only with making assumptions on padding that are not guaranteed.